# Program that runs in the background and wait several days for an event

Tags: c#, .net, background-process

I would like to write a program in C# that waits for a number of financial data to make a large move. I have a Bloomberg terminal and I know how to fetch data from Bloomberg in a C# program, with Bloomberg API.

But how can I make a program waits for a long time (several days) while running (maybe in the background) and intercepting this kind of events? Other programs I have written so far execute a list of steps, and then are closed. Is it possible to make without using too much CPU (especially because fetching data all the time from Bloomberg should use a lot of it)? How should I proceed?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What did you try yourself? Did you read upon threading, windows services, events etc etc if not i suggest you get a course in c#. And yes you can create an application that barely uses any cpu (0 - 1%) and barely uses any memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two solutions:

1. Write a simple windows service, which wait the time you need and fetch the data, sending data. That should not need much CPU, but maybe some I/O if you read and write a lot of data. (With a lot, i mean realy big data).
2. You write a simple application which will be started by the Windows Task Scheduler. In the task scheduler you can say, how often your app should be executed.

Comment: 1 if it needs to react to some call to it, 2 if it doesn't and you know before hand how often it will have to run.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know what were Windows Services made for. That will be helpful. And your second option is very smart too, but maybe less suited for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Windows Service hosting a WCF service.

When the terminal receives data, it can send a message to the WCF service, which in turn lets the Windows Service start processing the data.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have a hard time to understand what is a WCF service. And how can I interface it with a Windows Service?